# Find differential equation general solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

The task is to find $u_{xy}+yu_x+xu_y+xyu=0$ this equation general solutions.

First of all I wrote it as $\frac{d}{dx}(u_y+yu)+x(u_y+yu)=0$

Then marked $u_y+yu=t$  and got equation $t_x+xt=0$

And found it solution: $t=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}c(y)$

And I don't know how to solve this differential equation $u_y+yu=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}c(y)$

Answer (score 1):

Now you have

$$
u_y+y u = g(x)\phi(y)
$$

then

$$
u(x,y) = e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\left(\psi(x)+g(x)\int_0^y e^{\frac{\eta^2}{2}}\phi(\eta)d\eta\right)
$$